# Remote connections with Zend Studio

Tags: magento, zend-studio

I was looking for an IDE that will allow me to import all the necessary files to develop and debug Magento modules and found Zend Studio came recommended. I am having trouble connecting to my ftp to download the files. I created a remote connection using all of the credentials I had on Filezilla and when I test the connection it will succeed. Now when I go to the next step it tells me:

> The project directory you have entered does not exist on the server.
>   Please enter a valid project directory

The host name matches my ftp server, username and password are valid, the directory I'm connecting to exists on the server, and I'm on port 21 which is not interrupted by my firewall. I don't know if I should stick with Zend or not and I haven't been able to properly test it. Any advice on fixing this issue or any other IDE recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bad place to post such a question. Sorry. Here is for coding questions. To help you a little. Try to be sure that the settings for the remote path is correct in Zend Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the directory I'm connecting to exists on the server

Double-check that. Note, that the path you enter is relative:
there's a "Initial Directory" in "Remote Connection Profile", and "Project Directory" in project properties->"Remote Server Support"